# How to write a function that evaluates the first n terms only of array-like object and returns their sum?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have an array as follows:

```
A = np.array([a,b,c,d,e,f])
```

Each element in the array has a value that is equal to a scalar (e.g. maybe `a` is equal to 2, `b` is equal to 7, etc.). But `a` and `b` take a long time to evaluate, so it might take a couple of minutes for Python to determine the value `a`, a couple more minutes to determine the value of `b`, and similarly for the rest of the elements.

If there a way to define a function (lets call it `sumfirstn`) that evaluates the first n terms of `A` and computes their sum? For example, `sumfirstn(A,2)` would return `a+b`, `sumfirstn(A,3)` would return `a+b+c`, etc.

But (and this is important) `sumfirstn(A,2)` must *not* evaluate `c`, `d`, `e`, and `f`. It must *only* evaluate the relevant terms that are being added (to reduce computation time). Of course, `A[0:n].sum()` does the trick, but this requires Python computing the entire array `A`, which I don't want to do!

Any ideas? `A` doesn't have to be an array, could a list, data-frame, or be in some other form... whatever works.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on your terminology with "evaluating" here. I take it you *don't* have an array of scalars, otherwise there is no problem here. So I'm not sure what you have.

Comment: The way you are asking the question is making it seem like `array A` doesn't actually exist and that you just want to sum `a, b, c, d,...n` as they finish some previous calculation, but the output of the previous calculation is some kind of array. Am I correct? Why would evaluation of a,b,c take a long time if this was not the case?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The situation is difficult to explain. The array doesn't actually exist. I just have a number of expressions and want to compute the sum of the first n expressions. Each expressions returns a constant. Since I am iterating over various numbers for 'n', I need a way to do this relatively quickly.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what the problem with `A[0:n].sum()` is? I don't get what you mean with "but this requires Python computing the entire array `A`".

Comment: @MathewCarroll what kind of expressions? In my answer I used it as functions. But it can also be code if you use eval()

Comment: Be it a list, array or any data structure. In order to compute the sum of all/some of the elements it has to know the values of a,b... All you could do is slice the array to compute the sum of elements in which you are interested in if that helps

Comment: It sounds like you don't need to be using NumPy for this. If `a`, `b`, etc. are functions for instance, you're going to have to Python-level iterate anyways. You could maintain a NumPy array on the side with already-computed values perhaps, if you're planning on doing this more than once.

Comment: The most pythonic way of lazy-evaluation is a generator. It perfectly fits your requirement here (though you can evaluate middle without evaluating previous)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a generic solution to sum the first `n` items of *any* iterable, which not necessarily has to support indexing, slicing or a `sum` method.

If I understand correctly, the following should suffice as a generic solution.

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> 
>>> def first_n_sum(iterable, n):
...     return sum(islice(iterable, n))
```

Demo:

```
>>> first_n_sum([1,2,3,4], 3)
6
>>> first_n_sum((x for x in (1, 2, 3, 4)), 2)
3
>>> first_n_sum([], 123)
0
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> first_n_sum(OrderedDict([(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (-3, 'c'), (100, 'd')]), 3)
0
```

Note that there will be no error if the iterable cannot produce `n` values, just like slicing beyond the length of an array is okay. In this case the sum of all the elements will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that a,b,c,d,e,f are functions we can do something like:

```
def func():
    return 1+2+3

def sumfirstn(arr_of_functions, n):
    return sum([arr_of_functions[i]() for i in range(n)])

A = np.array([func, func, func, func, func, func])
sumfirstn(A,2)
```

Comment: Thanks. As you indicated in your comment, eval() will work when a,b,c,d,e,f are code rather than functions. Think this will work for this problem